How to expand a single-index DataFrame to a multiindex DataFrame in an efficient way? (python, pandas)
import pandas as pd
concordance_region = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    "country 1": pd.Series([1, 0], index=["region a", "region b"]),
    "country 2": pd.Series([0, 1], index=["region a", "region b"]),
    "country 3": pd.Series([0, 1], index=["region a", "region b"]),
}
)
display(concordance_region)
country_index = concordance_region.columns
region_index = concordance_region.index
sector_index = ['sector a','sector b']
country_sector = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([country_index, sector_index], names=["country", "sector"])
region_sector = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([region_index, sector_index], names=["region", "sector"])

concordance_region_expanded = pd.DataFrame([[1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1,0,1]], index=region_sector, columns=country_sector)
display(concordance_region_expanded)

I want to achieve the above expansion without hard-coding the number.
An option is that:
concordance_region_extended = pd.DataFrame(index=region_sector, columns=country_sector)
for region in region_index:
    for sector_1 in sector_index:
        for country in country_index:
            for sector_2 in sector_index:
                if sector_1 == sector_2 and concordance_region.loc[region, country] == 1:
                    concordance_region_expanded.loc[(region, sector_1),(country, sector_2)] = 1
concordance_region_expanded = concordance_region_expanded.fillna(value=0).infer_objects(copy=False)
concordance_region_expanded

But I think the above code is neither efficient nor elegant.
Any way to solve the above problem?

Code
use np.kron and identity matrix (identity matrix can be created with np.eye.)
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# taken from questioner's code
sector_index = ['sector a', 'sector b']
country_sector = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [country_index, sector_index], names=["country", "sector"])
region_sector = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [region_index, sector_index], names=["region", "sector"])


# start answer
n = len(sector_index)
out = pd.DataFrame(
    np.kron(concordance_region.values, np.eye(n)), 
    index=region_sector, columns=country_sector, dtype='int'
)

out


much simpler approach.+1

summary of logic: convert the multindexes to dataframes, cross join, map concordance_region to get the integers, do a boolean check based on your condition and unstack:
# you could possibly build a MultiIndex 
# of the three fields('region', 'country', 'sector') 
# - that way the cartesian join is done in one step, 
# within the MultiIndex creation
cc = country_sector.to_frame(index=False)
rr=region_sector.to_frame(index=False)
mapped=(concordance_region
        .stack(future_stack=True)
        .rename_axis(index=['region','country'])
        .rename('integers')
       )
# this captures your conditional logic
where_clause = (lambda df: df.integers
                             .where(df.sector_x.eq(df.sector_y))
                             .fillna(0)
                             .astype(int)
                )
(cc
.merge(rr,how='cross')
.set_index(['region','country'])
.join(mapped)
.assign(integers = where_clause)
.set_index(['sector_x','sector_y'], append=True)
.unstack(['country','sector_x'])
.droplevel(axis='columns', level=0)
)

country           country 1          country 2          country 3
sector_x           sector a sector b  sector a sector b  sector a sector b
region   sector_y
region a sector a         1        0         0        0         0        0
         sector b         0        1         0        0         0        0
region b sector a         0        0         1        0         1        0
         sector b         0        0         0        1         0        1

